# Trouble getting angular-google-chart to produce dual axis chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am having trouble getting angular-google-chart to produce a chart with two y-axis scales.  I have tried numerous example from online that work with google chart directly but have had no luck.  I have included what I believe to be a simple example.  This code is inside a controller.  Here is my code:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('core')
    .controller('DashboardErrorRatesController', DashboardErrorRatesController);

  DashboardErrorRatesController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$timeout', '$interval', 'Authentication', 'locale', 'Common', 'Query', 'googleJsapiUrl'];

  function DashboardErrorRatesController($rootScope, $scope, $state, $timeout, $interval, Authentication, locale, Common, Query, googleJsapiUrl) {

$scope.myChartObject = {
  type: 'LineChart',
  displayed: false,
  chartArea: { left: 100, top: 100, width: 400, height: 450 },
  data: {
    cols: [
      {
        id: 'issues',
        label: 'Issues per Week',
        type: 'string'
      },
      {
        id: 'pct_people',
        label: '% of People',
        type: 'number'
      },
      {
        id: 'avg_excallations',
        label: 'Average Escallations',
        type: 'number'
      }
    ],
    rows: [
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '0' }, { 'v': 0.39 }, { 'v': 0 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '1' }, { 'v': 0.17 }, { 'v': 31.063636363636363 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '2' }, { 'v': 0.12 }, { 'v': 30.46086956521739 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '3' }, { 'v': 0.09 }, { 'v': 49.612360674157316 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '4' }, { 'v': 0.06 }, { 'v': 26.975 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '5' }, { 'v': 0.04 }, { 'v': 32.82588235294117 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '6' }, { 'v': 0.03 }, { 'v': 25.413886666666667 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '7' }, { 'v': 0.03 }, { 'v': 35.716933333333344 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '8' }, { 'v': 0.02 }, { 'v': 11.689516129032258 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '9' }, { 'v': 0.01 }, { 'v': 10.20833125 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '10' }, { 'v': 0.01 }, { 'v': 29.311111111111114 }] },
      { 'c': [{ 'v': '10+' }, { 'v': 0.05 }, { 'v': 24.697815555555554 }] }
    ],
    options: {
      title: 'Something',
      isStacked: false,
      width: 300,
      height: 600,
      vAxis: {
        0: {
          title: '% of People',
          format: '#%'
        },
        1: {
          title: 'Average Escallations',
          format: '#,###.##'
        }
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Issues per Week'
      },
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
        0: { targetAxisIndex: 0 },
        1: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }
      }
    },
    formatters: {}
  }
};
  }
}());
```

I think this should produce a chart with both axis, but nope. It is almost as the angular-google-chart library (0.1.0) is using an old version of google chart but I cannot figure that out.

And here is the html:

```
<div google-chart chart="myChartObject"></div>
```

Comment: Are you using an angular directive for google charts? This looks like `angular-google-chart`. Can you provide more code (the view / html) or create a Plunkr?

Comment: Hey Tah,  Thanks!.  I have added the rest of the controller and the html.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  I changed the type from 'LineChart' to 'ComboChart'.  Whew that took a long time.  I hate when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for the vAxes keyword needing to be used when dealing with multiple axis(s). Took me a while to track this down.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).